# Return column names as a list in dataframe for a given condition of values in python

Tags: python-2.7, list, pandas, dataframe

given 1xN dataframe table, need to pick 5 largest values from the row and return the corresponding column names into a list. 
this is the dataframe sample:

```
            5        2         13         15         37        8         89    
PageRank  0.444384  0.44453  0.444695  0.444882  0.444759  0.44488  0.444648
```

Have tried this,

```
r = list(pr.loc['PageRank'].nlargest(5))
```

but the list created has only the values in rows, not the column names.
How to get the column names of 5 largest cell values?
for example, in the given dataframe, it should return

```
[15,37,13,89,5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `index`:

```
r1 = list(pr.loc['PageRank'].nlargest(5).index)
print (r1)
[15, 8, 37, 13, 89]
```

Or:

```
r1 = pr.columns[pr.loc['PageRank'].values.argsort()][-1:-6:-1].tolist()
print (r1)
[15, 8, 37, 13, 89]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get some added performance by using Numpy's `np.argpartition`.  I'll use it on the negative of the values in order to get the correct direction.

I wanted to use `np.argpartition` instead of sorting because it is `O(n)` rather than sorting which is `O(nlogn)`.

```
cols = pr.columns.values
rnks = -pr.values[0]
cols[np.argpartition(rnks, 5)[:5]].tolist()

['37', '15', '13', '8', '89']
```

---

**Timing**
You'll notice that `pir1` outperforms.  But also notice that `nlargest` asymptotically approaches the performance of `pir1` because they are both `O(n)`.

```
jez1 = lambda d: list(d.loc['PageRank'].nlargest(5).index)
jez2 = lambda d: d.columns[d.loc['PageRank'].values.argsort()[::-1]][:5].tolist()
jez3 = lambda d: d.columns[d.loc['PageRank'].values.argsort()[-1:-6:-1]].tolist()
pir1 = lambda d: d.columns.values[np.argpartition(-d.values[0], 5)[:5]].tolist()

res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000, 100000, 300000, 1000000],
    columns='jez1 jez2 jez3 pir1'.split(),
    dtype=float
)

for i in res.index:
    d = pd.DataFrame(dict(PageRank=np.random.rand(i))).T
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, {}'.format(j)
        res.at[i, j] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=200)

res.plot(loglog=True)
```

[image]

**Timing Ratio**
This table shows the ratio of each method's time relative to the minimum time taken for that particular length of array.

```
res.div(res.min(1), 0)

              jez1       jez2       jez3  pir1
10       20.740497   8.666576   6.738210   1.0
30       39.325125  11.962184  10.987012   1.0
100      30.121521  10.184435  10.173252   1.0
300      58.544734  11.963354  12.563072   1.0
1000     63.643729   9.361290   8.547374   1.0
3000     22.041026  15.977949  18.803516   1.0
10000     9.254778  11.620570  11.681464   1.0
30000     2.838243   7.522210   7.120721   1.0
100000    1.814005   7.486602   6.995017   1.0
300000    1.920776  13.213261  12.423890   1.0
1000000   1.332265   7.872120   7.225150   1.0
```

Comment: This is expected if the array is large enough that there is ever a tie within the first 5 ranks.

Comment: You are better innumpy like me, so no idea what is wrong, but in larger dataframe is problem.

Comment: I dont understand, so then solution is OK? I test it in small random Dataframes with 30, 50 columns and sometimes return same output as `nlargest`, sometimes not. Can you explan more? Thank you.

Comment: I try create [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47494480/2901002) for this, but was downvoted, so it seems was stupid. :(